# sifr not replacing font

Tags: css, flash, text, sifr, replace

I am trying to use sIFR to replace the headlines (e.g. The Tour of A Lifetime) on this page: http://tanciltown.com/ten-chimneys/

The font I want to swap in is Verlag by hoefler & frere jones.

I had this working the other day but it suddenly stopped working: the font does not replace.

All the js/css/flash files are linked correctly.  I tested my verlag.swf and it works.  And, I tested sIFR with a different font and the replacement worked.

Am I having issues because I have yet to buy a Verlag license for the server?

Or, is there some other ticky-tack issue?

Thank you for any help,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

```
<h3>The Tour of a Lifetime &copy;</h2>
```

There is your problem...

Also try fixing this.

```
// You defined museo
var museo = { src: 'flash/verlag.swf' };

// You activated verlag, but I don't see it defined...
sIFR.activate(verlag);
```

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately, I fixed the wrong closing tag and it still doesn't replace.

Comment: yup, that did it. d'oh! THANK YOU!